# Styling lists like Stackoverflow's side bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can the following code be styled:

```
<ul>
   <li><span>282</span>How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click</li>
   <li><span>3</span>How to change Bootstrap's dropdown's form?</li>
<ul>
```

So that it looks like this using just css:

[image]

Is that possible or would the html require divs? Stackoverflow uses a whole bunch of nested divs to do this but would it be possible to clean that code up using just an unordered list?

Comment: adding a few divs might make it easier.

Comment: I haven't examined it, but did you look at the CSS in the Web Inspector/Web developer tools of your browser?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, stackoverflow doesn't use lists. It uses a whole bunch of nested divs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own take would be:

```
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 4em;
    position: relative;
}

li span {
    position: absolute;
    left: -3em;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nMGJS/).

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JM4g3/15/)**

CSS:

```
li{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:170px;
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 0 5px 30px;
    color:blue;
}

span{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:5px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#333;
    width:25px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usualy use this code.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4k3d/)

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ul span{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    min-width:2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    text-indent: 0;
}
ul li{
    text-indent: -3.5rem;
    padding-left: 3.5rem;
    color: #0077cc;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```